# mvc show no picture if can't find file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc project. there is a column like this

```
<td>
    <img width="60" src='@Url.Content("~/Content/photos/" + @item.ID+".jpg")' alt="Image" />
</td>
```

But if no jpg file exists, I wanna show another general picture. How could I do that? Thanks

Comment: Are you using Razor with MVC? if so you could do this by using 'if' statements..

Comment: Yes I use Razor. but how to use razor to check? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it could use it like this

```
@if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Content/photos/" + @item.ID + ".jpg")))
                {
                    <img width="60" src='@Url.Content("~/Content/photos/" + @item.ID+".jpg")' alt="Image" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <img width="60" src='@Url.Content("~/Content/photos/noPic.jpg")' alt="Image" />
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming that your item ID is coming from your model. If this is the case you could use Razor to solve this problem. This is one solution:

```
@if (item.ID != null)
{
    <td>
        <img width="60" src='@Url.Content("~/Content/photos/" + @item.ID+".jpg")' alt="Image" />
    </td>
}
else 
{
    //code to show general picture here
}
```